# How to recover the IE settings after the Windows update

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-update

After the windows update, my IE settings such as Compatibility view settings, Internet Options/Security choices are all reset. How can I do to let the widows update keep these IE settings or after update, I can easily run something to recover it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your a home user, you should have no need to customize those settings.

You should accept the default security zone settings..Toools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default". If you have to tweak your default IE security zone settings to get some websites to work, **you are doing the wrong thing**.... unless you use a VPN connection to your company's intranet all of your websites should map to the Internet zone (File>Properties menu in IE to find out which IE security zone a domain is mapped to).

The user compatibility view list is depreciated on machines/networks using Enterprise Site Mode lists.

If you are using a managed domain, you should be using Enterprise Site Mode lists and lists from Microsoft to manage the Emulation Mode (aka documentMode) that your internal web sites use.

If you are a programmer with a good knowledge of the registry... you could export/import those registry keys responsible, but the user compatibility lists is redundant and is disabled with the update.

To map your localhost to the intranet zone (for development/test purposes) you manually add localhost or 127.0.0.1 to your IE Intranet sites list.